# c fscanf error checking

Tags: c, error-handling, scanf

I am using fscanf to read from a file in C. I was just wondering if I am correctly checking all the error conditions, and this is the most robust way to do so and I'm not missing anything.

```
FILE* fp;
char filename[] = "untitled";
int count;

char item1[1025];
char item2[1025];


fp = fopen(filename, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    perror("fopen");
    return -1;
}

count = fscanf(fp, "%1024s%1024s", item1, item2);
if (count == EOF) {
    if (ferror(fp)) {
        perror("fscanf");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: fscanf matching failure\n");
    }
    return -1;
}
else if (count == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: fscanf early matching failure\n");
    return -1;
}
else if (count != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: fscanf matched less items than expected\n");
    return -1;
}

if (fclose(fp) == EOF) {
    perror("fclose");
    return -1;
}
```

Thank you for your time.

EDIT after comments:

```
count = fscanf(fp, "%1024s%1024s", item1, item2);
if (count == EOF) {
    if (ferror(fp)) {
        perror("fscanf");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: fscanf reached end of file, no matching characters, no matching failure\n");
    }
    return -1;
}
else if (count != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: fscanf successfully matched and assigned %i input items, 2 expected\n", count);
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` does not return `EOF` on "matching failure". It returns `EOF` only on "input failure" (EOF, read errors, or encoding errors), and only if the input failure happens before any successful conversion and assignment. Therefore, if the return value is `EOF`, either `ferror` or `feof` must return nonzero.

Comment: @R: I was having a hard time following the man page for fscanf. I guess I misinterpreted the first line under the heading return value.

Comment: Yes, it's very confusing. Actually I just asked a question about this yesterday..

Comment: So can fscanf return EOF without setting an error indicator? The man page seems to imply that it is only set if a read error occurs?

Comment: It can also return `EOF` if it reached the end of the file before any conversion, in which case `feof` will be set.

Comment: @R: So feof is only set if it reached the end of the file without (any conversion or finding a matching error). Not if it successfully matches the entire file?

Comment: Like all stdio read functions, `scanf` behaves like repeated calls to `fgetc` in terms of how it modifies the `FILE` status, except that it has "magic lookahead" by which it can see that the next character in the stream is not part of the item to match, and leave it unread. I believe this also implies that a successful match of the whole file would not set `feof`, but the next read operation on the file would. However it's a complicated issue, and many implementations (including glibc) have issues where they do not conform to the C standard for `scanf`...

Comment: There can be other errors that make `fscanf()` return `EOF` that are not read errors (indicated by `ferror()` returning non-zero) and not `EOF`, eg. `ENOMEM`. The only way to check this, afaik, is setting `errno=0` before and checking it after. @Patrick

Comment: OTOH, a set `errno` isn't guaranteed at all by C, just by POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if (count == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: fscanf early matching failure\n");
    return -1;
}
else if (count != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: fscanf matched less items than expected\n");
    return -1;
}
```

doesn't stand the test of usability. These cases are not distinguishable by the error message; if you must report both options to the user, then why not

```
if (count != NMATCHES)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: wanted %d items, found %d\n", NMATCHES, count);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Your fscanf works only when you use fprintf with the same %1024s%1024s, otherwise I don't think you can get the strings in the two char variables.
2. You are limiting your code to take the size of 1K, you should never use hardcoding of values, and what will you do if you string size goes beyond 1K (extreme case), so you have to limit your string size in the file to be less than 1K, which you cannot expect everytime unless you have the control of writing the data to same file.

Comment: In this case, I do have control over the file.