# fscanf: is error or EOF possible without EOF returned?

Tags: c++, scanf, stdio

I have a C++ program that reads from a file that I expect to have a bunch of identically formatted records. I want to stop reading if I encounter something unexpected whether that means an ill-formatted record or some input failure and I want to differentiate between these different conditions.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794420/c-fscanf-error-checking) and looked at the `fscanf()` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) and I'm not sure if `fscanf()` can indicate an error or EOF without returning EOF. From my understanding of both those links it's possible that an error occurs or EOF occurs even if `fscanf()` returns a value of 0 or greater so I would have to call `ferror()` and `feof()` regardless of what value `fscanf()` returns. I can't seem to find how a return value of EOF is of any use to the caller.

Say I expect my file to have a bunch of records with 4 values. Would the code below properly handle any end of file and input error conditions?

```
  int ret;
  int field1;
  int field2;
  int field3;
  int field4;
  while ((ret = fscanf(pFile, "%d %d %d %d", &field1, &field2, &field3,
                       &field4)) == 4) {
    // do whatever with fields
  }
  if (ferror(fp)) {
    // some input error occurred
  } else if (feof(fp)) {
    // end of file occurred
  } else {
    assert(ret != EOF);
    // encountered record that didn't match expected format
  }
```

Update: So I'm going to add the documentation from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) because it seems to differ slightly in describing what condition no longer causes EOF to be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is error or EOF possible without EOF returned?

Yes it is. You could also get a return value between 0 and 3. cplusplus.com is somewhat notoriously sloppy. Let's take a look at [cppreference.com's page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) instead.

> *Return value: Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned.*

There are a couple different scenarios. Let's break it down into cases:

1. **If it has successfully assigned to the first receiving argument** then you'll get a positive value, guaranteed. Let's say it's assigned to two variables and then hits EOF. It'll return `2` and `feof()` will return true.
2. Otherwise, if it **hasn't assigned to the first receiving argument and gets a matching failure** it'll return `0`. What's a matching failure? That's when it's matching a specifier like `%d` and doesn't get a valid integer. If the input is `foobar` then `%d` will fail to match.

   Or, less commonly, it's when it's looking for a literal character and doesn't see it. For instance if your format string expected each number to be enclosed in brackets (`"[%d] [%d] [%d] [%d]"`) then it would return `0` if the input didn't start with `[`.
3. Otherwise, if it **hasn't assigned to the first receiving argument and gets a EOF or a read error** it'll return `EOF`. Note that a *read* error is different from a *matching* error. A read error is when the OS returns an I/O error trying to read from disk.

   A return value of `EOF` signals either end-of-file or I/O error. If you don't care about the distinction you could just abandon your loop and move on with the program. If, however, you want to print an error message on `ferror()` and treat `feof()` as success then checking `ret` isn't sufficient; you have to call one or both of those functions. It's up to you if you want to do that or not.

> Say I expect my file to have a bunch of records with 4 values. Would the code below properly handle any end of file and input error conditions?

Yep. Looks good to me.

---

For what it's worth, I recommend against using `scanf()` and `fscanf()`. They're complicated and make handling input errors robustly more difficult than necessary. This question is a great demonstration. It's better to use `fgets()` to read an entire line and `sscanf()` to parse it. That way if there's bad input you don't have a partial line sitting around jamming up future reads.

Comment: Looks great but can you clarify the "If it successfully reads even a single byte it must return a non-negative result."? For example this https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf documentation says "or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned." which to me means it only returns a non-negative result if it matched 1 value.

Comment: *"If it* ***successfully reads..."*** is the key here. If there is a successful conversion made (and a `char` or string or `int` or `double` can all be satisfied with the read of a single byte, e.g. `2`), then the return will be non-zero as there has been at least one successful conversion before any error occurs. In the case of an input failure, if you had `"%s %d"` as your format string, and you successfully read, e.g. `2`, and then there was no more input, then an *input failure* occurs. (there is not enough input for all conversions specified).

Comment: Even `sscanf` has a serious problem for numeric input. Numeric overflow has undefined behavior. If you can for an `int` value using `%d`, and the input contains, say, `10000000000`, `sscanf` can do literally anything. The `strto*()` functions can reliably handle errors (though they way they report them is a bit tricky).

Comment: Ok, I knew these comments were coming based on previous questions. I understand fscanf use is discouraged but that seems orthogonal to understanding how an available function, i.e. `fscanf`, actually works. As far as overflow I use width specifiers which I omitted for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to explain the return value of the `fscanf` family of functions with examples.

```
// The string contains valid data given the format specifier.
// Expect ret to be 1.
int ret = sscanf("10", "%d", &n);

// The string contains data but not what the user expects to see.
// Expect ret to be 0.
int ret = sscanf("abcd", "%d", &n);

// The string contains no data .
// Expect ret to be EOF.
int ret = sscanf("", "%d", &n);
```

In all these cases, you can expect the same behavior if you have leading spaces.

```
// Expect ret to be 1.
int ret = sscanf("  10", "%d", &n);

// Expect ret to be 0.
int ret = sscanf("  abcd", "%d", &n);

// Expect ret to be EOF.
int ret = sscanf("  ", "%d", &n);
```